# If $H \trianglelefteq G$ has finite index in G, $a$ has finite order in $G$, and $\gcd(n,m)=1$, then $a \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with $[G:H] = n < \infty$. If $a \in G$ where $\lvert a \rvert = m < \infty$ (that is the order of $a$ is finite $m$) and $\gcd(n,m) = 1$, then $a \in H$.

I don't know what direction to go in. I thought perhaps looking for a contradiction might help, but this might be the wrong direction to go in. Assume $a \notin H$ and note $G/H = \{ H, g_1H, \ldots g_{n-1}H \}$, so $aH \neq H$, that is $aH = g_kH$ for some $1 \le k \le n-1$. Then $H = a^mH = (g_k)^m H$, so $(g_k)^m \in H$.

Comment: This is a good start. Have you thought about $aH$ as an element of the **quotient group** $G / H$? What happens if we apply Lagrange's Theorem to $aH$ within $G / H$?

Comment: What is $(n,m)=1$ supposed to note, and what do you mean by $|a|=m$

Comment: @Cornman $(n,m)=1$ means the gcd of $n$ and $m$, so they are relatively prime. And $\lvert a \rvert$ is the order of $a$.

Comment: @user330531: I thought so, but you should note it that way, to make it clear in the firstplace.

Comment: @KennyWong Alright, then $\lvert g_k H \rvert \mid m$ and by Lagrange $\lvert g_k H \rvert \mid \lvert G/H \rvert = n$. Since $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime, $\lvert g_k H \rvert = 1$, which would imply $g_k H = H$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user330531 That's exactly right. :)

Comment: @KennyWong Alright thanks for verifying! That was a spot on hint. I can accept an answer by you if you want to make it.

Comment: @user330531 Glad it helped! Feel free to accept Stefan's answer, or write one yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(aH)^m = a^mH = H \quad \quad (aH)^n = H$$

This means that the order of $aH$ divides both $m$ and $n$ by Lagrange, then as $(m,n) = 1$: $$o(aH) = 1 \implies aH = H \implies a \in H$$

Comment: How do we know $(aH)^n = H$? I understand $o(aH)$ is at most $n$ and must divide the order of the quotient group, namely $n$, by Lagrange.

Comment: @user330531 The order of the group $G/H$ is n, so every element to the power $n$ will give you the identity, right? $o(aH)$ has to divide $m$ too, as $(aH)^m = H$

Comment: Oh right, the order of any element in $G/H$ will divide the order of the quotient group and thus $n$ will contain some positive integer multiples of the order of $aH$, that's clear I should have seen that. Thanks.